# Is there an easier way to get the lesser of two values in Swift

Tags: swift

I'd like to assign the lesser of two values to a variable.  **In Ruby** I would do something like:

```ruby
my_var = [value_one, value_two].min
```

**In Swift**, of course, I can do this:

```swift
var myVar = 0.0
if valueOne < valueTwo {
    myVar = valueOne
} else {
    myVar = valueTwo
}
```

But, I'm wondering if there is a cleaner, more succinct solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var myVar = min(valueOne, valueTwo)
```

`min` is a standard library function that takes the lesser of two (or least of several — it's variadic) `Comparable` values.